# How to make a similar animation to Flappy Bird in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm creating a game like flappy bird where the bird flaps his wings only when the screen is touched, but I'm having a problem activating the animation when the screen is touched.

```
batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(myTimeState, false), x, y); //the myTimeState is 0 to render the 1st frame only.
```

Then when the screen is touched I do this:

```
//myTimeStep is just basically a controllable timeState for the animation only

    if(Gdx.input.justTouched){
         myTimeState = timeState;
    }else if(Gdx.input.justTouched == false && animation.isAnimationFinished(timeState)){
         myTimeState = 0;
    }
```

I don't think the animation is able to play all the frames because myTimeStep become 0 immediately after finishing to touch the screen. Also I don't think this is the right way of doing it, if you guys have better ideas or solution please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want the animation to be played only when the screen is touched down and to stop at the moment of touch up?

Comment: Nope but that's what is happening with my code, I want something like flappy bird, when the screen is touched the bird flaps his wings then after the animation is just a normal sprite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably several ways to achieve this. You'll need to increment your timeState, of course, and also it depends how long your animation is and if you want it to loop.

If you've created your animation to play only once, and then stop (until the screen is touched again), you could simply set your myTimeState to 0 when the screen is touched, and then increment it every frame. The animation will run through and then "stop" on its own when it reaches the end (as you said no loop). The next time someone touches the screen, your myTimeState is set back to 0 and the animation starts again.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get it at first. So when I touch the screen I just set the timeState to 0.

Comment: Another question please, when I set the timeState to 0 does the game think that the animation hasn't been played yet? is it the reason why the animation is played all over again?

Comment: Don't forget you incrementing the time state. That is the key. At timestate 0, it will show the first image in your animation. In your game, you then increment the time state by some deltaTime - like Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(). When you render,animation class figures out which image to show based on your accumulated timestate. If you don't loop anim., once your timestate passes the images*timePerFrame (animation constructor), your render will continually show the last image in your animation (could be non flying img). Setting timestate back to 0, restarts animation (if timestate incremented)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to ensure your animation's playmode is set to Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL. It's a default setting, but if you set it somewhere to LOOPED, nothing would work as expected.

Secondly, I wouldn't use Input.justTouched() in this case. Instead, a listener in your input processor would be a great fit. Here's an example with Stage. If you have no idea what input processor is, here's tutorial on [event handling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling) and [class documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html).

```
stage.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            if(button == Input.Buttons.LEFT) {
                timeState = 0;
            }
            return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }
    });
```

You can pick what's going to be displayed (animation's keyframe or sprite) based on result of animation.isAnimationFinished()

```
    if(animation.isAnimationFinished(timeState)) {
        //draw some sprite
    } else {
        //draw animation keyframe
    }
```

I haven't checked it but there's a possibility, that this could lead to the last frame being cut out, because as soon as it gets displayed, animation.isAnimationFinished() will return true. I may be wrong, so you'll have to check it. If it becomes an issue, you can add your sprite as the last frame of your animation. When animation ends, it frezzes on the last frame, which would be your static sprite.

In both cases you'll get your animation played at the beginning of game because timeStep equal to 0. I see 2 solutions, I advise you to take the second:

1. Set timeStep to a large number, that is for sure larger than your animation's duration. Animation.isAnimationFinished() will then return true.
2. Introduce boolean variable isAnimationPlayed that:

   - is initialized with false,
   - gets set to true in your click listener,
   - gets set to false during isAnimationFinished(), which is called each frame only when isAnimationPlayed is true,
   - is used in draw() method to determine what to display.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set your `timeState` to the duration of the animation.

Comment: What do you mean? for example each frame is rendered for 0.33 so I should do timeState = 0.33? but the time state needs to be timeState += deltaTime.